# How to rotate API and application keys in Datadog

Tags: datadog

In Datadog, I have a couple of API and Application keys that are actively being used by internal applications, most of the keys are owned by individual persons, who are no longer in the team. Now how do I rotate them and transfer them to a service account instead of an individual person without downtime or less downtime? Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: I asked around and there's no particular best practice beyond creating the new keys, switching your apps over, and turning off the old keys. I recommend that you do rotate the API keys as well as application keys, because former employees could still use them to get access. (I work at DD)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

API keys do not need to be replaced when a user is deleted. They belong to your entire account, and if the creator of the tag is deleted, the API key still works just fine. API keys are like the password to your organization, and are used for submitting data.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/account_management/api-app-keys/#api-keys

---

Application keys are used for automating behaviors in your account. Anything a user can do in the account like create a dashboard or edit a monitor, the application key will be required for when using the API. Application keys **are** tied to a specific user and will inherit all the permissions of that user. So if that user does not have the ability to edit dashboards, neither will the Application Key.

You can avoid the issue of general automation tasks being tied to a specific human by utilizing [service accounts](https://docs.datadoghq.com/account_management/org_settings/#service-accounts). Service accounts are meant to be robotic users, which can be provided roles and create application keys. They should be linked to a common distribution list that your team has access to so it's not tied to a single person.

Comment: Any idea how to get the `service_account_id` to be able to to use service accounts through the Datadog API as required in documentation? https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/service-accounts/

Comment: @Vab I'd probably just use the list all endpoint and find it from there. or check the service accounts section in my org settings: https://app.datadoghq.com/organization-settings/service-accounts

it's embedded in the url

Comment: thanks for the hint, I could get it from the url, but through requesting the API to https://api.datadoghq.eu/api/v2/service_accounts using the `API and APP key pairs` in the Header failed and got the `404 Not Found`, `The resource could not be found` Error. 

I'm using this doc https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/service-accounts/ but please suggest a better documentation (if any), since here there are no topics for `Listing`, `Creating`, or `Deleting` a Service Account via API.

Thank you again.